# Let android phone act on actions on a website

Tags: android, push-notification

it's just a theoretical problem i'm thinking about. Maybe you can broaden my horizon.
Lets assume there is a simple website where I can type in a color and hit the send button. So I choose the color red. Now I want my Android phone to receive the message with the color 'red' that just got submitted on the website and change the background color of the listening app to the just submitted color.
Now my question is, how does my phone know that there has just happened a change on the server? Of course, I could steadily send requests if something has changed or listen on the socket all the time, but that wouldn't be battery efficient...?

Maybe you have something efficient in mind to listen to these updates?

Comment: Yeah thanks, that could be a solution but I need to use this google service. Would a persistant TCP/IP connection be another efficient solution that doesnt ruin my battery?

Comment: you could use anyother xmpp based notification system. (which basically is a long pulling system)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps
>   developers send data from servers to their Android applications on
>   Android devices.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html